# How to validate array which is dynamic in nature Like sometime string and some time objects

Tags: joi, json-schema-validator, hapi

I am Using @hapi/joi.
I have an array which store value dynamically, it store string, empty string (an empty array) or an Objects ({"userid": "111jh2jh322j3h2j3h", "msg": 1}).

So it will be like this:

```
type1-> member: []
type2-> member: ["firstString", "secondString"]
type3-> member: [{"userid": "111jh2jh322j3h2j3h", "msg": 1}, {"userid": "7875jh2jh3545hj3hth", "msg": 0}]
```

I am confused that how to do validation on @Hapi/joi.

Currently My implementation is:

```
member: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().allow('')),
```

I know that If we have an object which is stored under an array then I will do the validation is like:

```
member: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
      userid: Joi.string(),
      msg: Joi.number(),
    })),
```

Any help is really appreciated for that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It will be like this:

```
member: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().allow(''), Joi.object({
        userid: Joi.string(),
        msg: Joi.number(),
      })),
```